# How to query nested json using AlaSQL

Tags: javascript, json, alasql

I have the following json:

```
values={
"1159":{"date":"2019-07-01T19:46:42.393Z","location":"southside","team_member_id":1159,"fullname":"Heather Smith","score":[3.909090909090909],"avg":3.909090909090909},
"485":{"date":"2019-10-03T13:46:40.594Z","location":"murray","team_member_id":485,"fullname":"John Page ","score":[3.9166666666666665,3.5652173913043477,3.9375],"avg":3.8064613526570046},
"1305":{"date":"2019-09-18T03:00:02.791Z","location":"wpad","team_member_id":1305,"fullname":"Destiny Copeland","score":[3.7916666666666665,3.4444444444444446,3.9545454545454546,3.4],"avg":3.6476641414141415},
"1334":{"date":"2019-08-24T18:50:20.206Z","location":"strawberry hill","team_member_id":1334,"fullname":"Bryan Davis","score":[3.8181818181818183,3.85],"avg":3.834090909090909},
"2051":{"date":"2019-09-06T19:54:10.330Z","location":"carbondale","team_member_id":2051,"fullname":"Mary Defreitas ","score":[4,3.7083333333333335],"avg":3.854166666666667},
"2042":{"date":"2019-09-16T19:29:22.897Z","location":"carbondale","team_member_id":2042,"fullname":"Henry Joe","score":[3.9565217391304346,3.9583333333333335,3.869565217391304,3.9583333333333335,3.8333333333333335]
}
```

I need to query this json based on the location using alasql. When I type this query, it doesn't work:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE location=carondale',[values]);
console.log(res);
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: I'm curious why you need alasql to do this?

Comment: `const res = Object.entries(values).filter(([,{location}])=>location==="carondale")` and you're done...